# R program-output : How to include R id stamp in output?

Tags: r

So whenever I run my code and get this output

```
   Values   Random
1   4       0.1
2   3       1.2
3   6       1.3
4   6 
5   7
6
7
```

So I have this first column of numbers that R just generates by itself whenever I run my code
....So I basically use the functions below to put my R output to an excel spreadsheet ...But when I do that They dont include those random numbers that R just generates...I want to include that in my spreadsheet...How would I go about that ?

```
let<-loadWorkbook("randomn.xls",create=TRUE)
createSheet(let,name="sheet1")
writeWorksheet(let,data,sheet="sheet1")
saveWorkbook(let)
```

Comment: Please post the code that generates `data`, so we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the excel package you are using, try setting `row.names = TRUE`

PS: Check the `writeWorksheet` API for the exact name of the parameter